# Replace non matching characters regex

Tags: regex, vim, replace, pattern-matching

I'm trying to create a regex which does a replace of every characters which is not within a search pattern.

p.e.
**Input**

```
whatever text text and more text
test 2 12000 text and more text
text and text
text 3 text more text
1-2000 and more text
```

search pattern:

```
let @/ = '^test \zs2 \d\d\d\d\d\s.*\n\(.*\n\)\{-}text 3\ze'
```

(matching from just before '2' till just after '3')

I want to replace all other characters outside the matching with the character `_`.

**expected output**

```
________________________________
_____2 text and more text
text and text
text 3_______________
_____________
```

I use this regex which works fine but does not work if there are multiple lines in search pattern:

```
exe "%s/\\(@/\\)\\zs\\|./\\=submatch(1)!=''?'':'_'/g"
```

How can I make it work also with multiple lines in search pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modyfing alpha bravo's solution and adapting to vim:

```
:%s/\(2\_.*3\)*[^\r\n]/\1_/g
```

Should do the trick.

The key here is `\_.`  which matches any character including newlines.
Which is the equivalent to `/s` in PCRE

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern `(2.*3)*[^\r\n]` with `gs` options and replace with `$1_`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rU1yS2/1)

Comment: Don't understand what you're writing. Your solution doesn't seem to be in vimscript isn't it?

Comment: No it is not, it's in PCRE, but I thought it would get you started if you can translate it.